# How to change a Winform application into a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-controls

I do have a Winform solution with two projects. Now I would like to have a UserControl which I can use in my new WPF application.

**Question:**
What is the best and easiest way to create such UserControl? Is it better to open a new project from scratch or is there a way to create such UserControl directly from the existing winform solution?

Comment: do you want to create a WPF user control and use it inside you winforms application or the other way arround?

Comment: @Amit the other way around (Winform in WPF)

Comment: You have your answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reuse Winforms controls in WPF and viceversa. But think whether you really need it.

WPF provides great support for DataBinding whereas Winforms provides very little support for it. Patterns to implement UI differs in both technologies, etc.

Consider reimplementing the UserControl with patterns specific to respective UI technology rather than trying to reuse it in different UI technology.

If at all you want to reuse it: [Here you go.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751797%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The reason why I like to use the Winform control is that I have this code allready and it works. Therefore I think it's the easier way simply to use the same code in the WPF application instead of re-programm it again. What is your opinion?

Comment: My opinion will be move the business logic to separate library(dll) and share the business logic in both wpf and winforms project while implementing the UI separately. Ideally I'll not try to reuse the UI unless there's a compelling reason, though I've done it successfully.